# Ranking functions by order of growth

Tags: big-o-notation

Did I correctly rank these functions by order of growth? I ranked them from smallest to largest (left to right). I have to eventually prove this ranking, so just looking to make sure that I have the right understanding.

$n^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\log_2 n}}}, \quad 10^{\log_2 (\log_2 n)}, \quad 2^{\sqrt{2 \log_2 (n)}}, \quad \sqrt{2}^{\log_2 (n)}, \quad (n^2-3n)^3, \quad e^n, \quad (n+1)!$

Comment: No. This is wrong, but it can be fixed with a single swap.

Comment: @Steven a hint please?

Comment: Rewrite the first $4$ functions in the form $2^{\text{something}}$ and then look at the exponents.